# If not MATLAB, what software/programming language should I use to simulate/animate wave functions in various potentials + more? (example given)

Tags: matlab, python, computational-physics, quantum-mechanics, wave-propagation

I want to integrate programming into my learning in math and science in a very specific way. I want to create visualizations and simulations of concepts I am learning. When I learn a numerical method of graphing differential equations I want write a program that can do it for me, when I learn about tunnelling in QM I want to be able to animate it (maybe even write something that can solve a misc. set of potentials), when I learn about coupled oscillators I want to be able to write a program that animates pendulums connected by springs, etc. I also want all these animations to not depend on a built in physics engine. I want the equations inputed by me. Is MATLAB capable of all this? If not, what is?

Here are some example from other people:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cV2fkDscwvY

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N524t6wdlcM&t=420s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KvyXQmaUWzU&t=3s

I understand some of the above use matplotlib with python. I have tried using it but have run into problems that just dont arise in trying to learn Matlab. Even when I copy/paste code into Jupyter notebooks, things fail to run or animate. I don't know how to interpret the error messages and there are simply not enough resources online to figure it out. Maybe I need to be told that its not too hard and I am lazy. I respect that. I am good at and enjoy math and physics. I have only been remotely interested in programming for a couple of days. So, be harsh but be understanding.

Comment: I am a long time MATLAB user and quite proficient at it -actually it is my goto language for prototyping- but learning scipy/numpy libraries is the future facing way. But if you want to stick with MATLAB (and I can suggest it, MATLAB has everything you need), you can use GNU/Octave. It has same syntax, lacks some features but it is open source. Julia is also high level/high performance programming language, it became popular two years ago and its user base is constantly growing. This is my two cents

Comment: If you have access to Matlab, then it is a good tool for what you want to do. But if you need a free tool, try Python (my preference) or Julia. One great reason to use Matlab for me is the excellent Chebfun software https://www.chebfun.org which is also useful for what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is very good. Several studies show that doing something stays deeper in memory than reading about it and testing things for yourself will give you a good intuitive feeling. Now, to your questions:

**Is MATLAB capable of all this?** Yes, it has strong numerical and GUI capabilities

**If not, what is?** As mentioned by Abdullah Ali Sivas, you could either try Octave or Julia. I would add Scilab (Similar to Matlab and Octave but slightly different syntax, I like it because it has a simulator for block diagrams) and last but not least **Python**. I don't use Jupyter notebooks that much, for me they're more useful when documenting or presenting something. I would recommend you to install Anaconda which comes with the GUI Spyder (which you'll find familiar if you already know Matlab) and write code there. If you have problems re-running some code then googling the error message or asking in stack exchange is usually very helpful. And learning programming is absolutely a must, at the beginning perhaps a steep learning curve but totally worth it. There is a lot of free good information, so learning Python for a couple of weeks is a very wise investment.